# MYSQL #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to this select:

Ccid and name of the defendants with more crime charges in each year,
separated by gender (more charges in their gender). Notes: in case of a tie, all
the defendants in the tie should be listed. The results should be ordered by year
in descendent order, and by gender, ccid and name in ascendent order.

I tried this:

```
    SELECT p.nome, arg.pessoa
FROM pessoa p, arguido arg
WHERE p.ccid = arg.pessoa
    AND MAX(arg.crime) IN (SELECT ano.crime  -- falta caso de desempate
                           FROM crime c
                           WHERE arg.crime = c.id
                           AND p.genero = "M")
    AND MAX(arg.crime) IN (SELECT ano.crime 
                           FROM crime c
                           WHERE arg.crime = c.id
                           AND p.genero = "F")
ORDER BY ano.crime DESC, p.genero,p.ccid,p.nome ASC;
```

And I'm getting this error:

> #1111 - Invalid use of group function

but I don't understand why.

The database Tables and Schema are the following:

[image: The database Tables and Schema]

Now I tried this way

```
SELECT p.ccid, p.nome
FROM pessoa p
JOIN arguido arg ON p.ccid = arg.pessoa
WHERE COUNT(arg.pessoa) > (SELECT COUNT(arg.pessoa)
                            FROM pessoa p
                            JOIN arguido arg ON p.ccid = arg.pessoa)
GROUP BY arg.decisao;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.  I removed the inconsistent database tags.

Comment: You are using the MAX function in an incorrect way

Answer (score 0):

You are using MAX function in a wrong way, you need to do a subquery to get the max value:

```
SELECT p.nome, arg.pessoa
FROM pessoa p, arguido arg
WHERE p.ccid = arg.pessoa
     AND (SELECT MAX(crime) FROM arguido) IN (SELECT ano.crime  -- falta caso de desempate
                       FROM crime c
                       WHERE arg.crime = c.id
                       AND p.genero = "M")
     AND (SELECT MAX(crime) FROM arguido) IN (SELECT ano.crime 
                       FROM crime c
                       WHERE arg.crime = c.id
                       AND p.genero = "F")
ORDER BY ano.crime DESC, p.genero,p.ccid,p.nome ASC;
```

Any ways, you have more problems:

```
SELECT ano.crime 
FROM crime c
WHERE arg.crime = c.id
AND p.genero = "F"
```

this subquery is going to give an error because it won´t find ano.crime

And I wouldn´t use that join but use an explicit and modern JOIN

Comment: I have tried this way, and its giving me the same error

Comment: You are using the COUNT(arg.pessoa)  again in the wrong way

Comment: Instead of using where, use having